# Cant use my Device as a Emulator in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, usb, device

I have device **Micromax A63 which have android 4.2 jelly bean.**

But my problem is when **I run android application via eclipse I cant found my device is attached with USB cable in eclipse**.

When I connect with USB cable I have 4 option on my device.

1. USB Storage
2. Media Device
3. Camera
4. Charge Only

how to use my device as a emulator please help me.
Please help me.

Comment: select media device.. and make sure you installed your mobile drivers in computer..

Comment: ofcorse I had installed and choose As u said. but nothing changed

Comment: for me..In micromax i installed the MOBOROBO software in windows then it worked fine

Comment: Ok it this software for mobile?

Comment: no..it is  for windows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open settings
2. About phone
3. Tab "Build Number" 7 times
4. Go back to settings and enable developer option

Now your phone is a developer phone ;)

Comment: But Still I cant found my device. on emulater

Comment: kaha to @PoojaRoy ki Android Coders Group mai reply do i m using same devoce for testing

Answer (score 1):

Go to developer option > (Select) USB debugging option.

Comment: Developer where? in android settings-> App I doesnt have any developer option

Comment: Tap multiple time(Might be 7) on About Phone > Build Number and than you can see developer option.

Comment: go to setting --> developers options(Second last option) --> enable USB debugging

Comment: if you didn;t find the developer option then go to about phone and tap 7 times on build number.it will enable your developer options.

Comment: Dont have option in Settings as you told.

Comment: you do not have About Phone option in setting?

Comment: Hey I am being developer and I got usb debugging option enable but I still cant found deice on Emulater

Comment: @PoojaRoy come on Android Coders Chat Room

Answer (score 1):

On your device go to settings > developer options > select USB debugging > check it ..
Come to eclipse select run configuration under the run menu , select your device as a target device.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly get the USB drivers from the offical website, But it seems to me that Micromax have not posted an offical USB driver support(Poor customer service) , try re installing the MOBORO usb tool , which must do it `http://www.idroidspace.com/download-micromax-usb-drivers/`
After that follow plain instructions Of setting the debugging option "On" on your phone that is found at (as given on offical [google android developer webiste](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice)  )

On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options.

Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.